# Redirecting network requests in Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, storybook

I've been fighting with this for so long! I have network requests that need to happen in component stories, but they get sent out on Storybook's port which does them no good.

The closest I've gotten is this Storybook middleware:

```
const middleware = (router) => {
  router.post('/Search/myUrl', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    res.redirect(307, 'http://localhost:61324/Search/myUrl');
  });
};
```

This does redirect the post request, but it gets caught in CORS and I have not been able to get past that no matter what headers I send. I have found very little online, this doesn't seem like a rare situation so I think I must be missing a simpler solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to proxy your request instead of redirecting it (e.g. using http-proxy-middleware). It should solve the problem with CORS. CORS are checked only on browser level and because of redirect browser knows that you are calling external server, but with proxy browser would think that you are calling Storybook's port and shouldn't complain.

Comment: Aha! Took me a while to get it going, but you were exactly right and now it works. Thank you!